# Is there a place in which a portal to another dimension could be hidden for five years, but then discovered by children?

Tags: science-fiction, urban-fantasy

I am writing a story in which two children, ages 12-14 years old, discover a portal to another dimension. The portal is roughly the size of an average door and has existed for five years prior to their discovery of it.

It wasn't protected by some kind of password or disguised, neither it was in a place one could hardly access, such as far as from the suburbs in which they live or inside a private home.

But my problem here is figuring out a good location to ensure such a scenario happens. Is there a way for a door-sized portal to another dimension stay hidden for five years but then be discovered by two normal children? The best answer in this case is the one regarding the best location/placement in order to maximize the chances of such a scenario happening, preferably *why* no one but the children would check out such a location.

Comment: This sounds like a plot element, not a worldbuilding problem

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica, how is it different from other questions asking for how things could be hidden?

Comment: Where a portal can be hidden and found by children is specific to your story, not a rule of a world.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica, it's set in a real-world, present-day suburb.

Comment: Are these kids supposed to be the first ones that are able to fall through this gateway, or is the expectation that there are others before them that fell through it?

Comment: They are supposed to be the first to fall through this gateway and the first to encounter it other than the person who created it.

Comment: And in what part of the world exactly is this suburb? Is it the classic US scenario or in another part of the world? Is there only houses and small businesses or something else?

Comment: I think the answer is in the back of a wardrobe in the other room.....

Comment: Sometimes true murder stories on television begin with boys finding a dead body that turns out to have been dead for days, weeks, months, years, or decades, and an investigation starting.  Possibly one of the kids in the story want's to go someplace farther off the beaten path through the woods or whatever than they have been before, something, and gets the other kid to go along, and no adult or any other kid would have wanted to go that far off the beaten path in years.  Think of a reason for one of the kids to drag the other kid that far, like getting a lost toy plane or a drone.

Comment: @Thucydides Good point. :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be in a bush reserve. For example, Kepa bush reserve is right next to a shopping centre, but has very steep and uneven ground; you generally wouldn't want to leave the path. The portal might not be visible from the path, and being covered by vegetation barely visible right next to it. A portal might not be lost until some children decided to play explorers.